# C++11 - tuple and move semantics

Tags: c++, c++11

Should this sample code compile?
`clang` and `g++` accept it, while `icc 14` refuses to do so, complaining on `auto t = ...` that the `std::unique_ptr`'s copy constructor is undefined.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <tuple>

std::tuple<std::unique_ptr<int[]>, int> foo()
{
    std::unique_ptr<int[]> a;
    unsigned int b;
    auto t = std::make_tuple(std::move(a), b); 
    return std::move(t);
}

int main()
{
    foo();
}
```

Comment: what's the issue with returning rvalues?

Comment: but I'm returning a `T`, not a `T&&`. I think it should be safe anyway

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice that. :)

Comment: Still, you should remove the call to `std::move` on the return value, because it isn't necessary, and it inhibits RVO.

Comment: OK, thanks for the hint, although that's not the point of my question

Comment: That's why it's a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would think it should compile: the result from `std::make_tuple()` is a temporary `std::tuple<T...>` and it is supposed to move construct its members. More precisely, `std::tuple<T...>`'s move constructor is defaulted which should result in memberwise move construction.

Clearly, there is no real need to assign the result of `std::make_tuple()` to `t`. If you choose to introduce this variable, you shouldn't `std::move(t)` when returning: when the expression in a `return` statement is a local variable, it is treated as if it is an rvalue anyway. The extra `std::move()` inhibit copy/move elision, however.

Comment: The extra std::move() inhibit copy/move elision, however. +1

Comment: So Intel's compiler is not as C++11-ready as they advertise it, after all

Comment: @akappa: It may be the compiler, it may be the library. You might want to create a test case which doesn't use the library at all but uses a `struct` with a defaulted move constructor containing a `std::unique_ptr<int>` and see how that behaves.

Comment: Perhaps it's the library. With this code: http://pastebin.com/t39F1iiH ICC does not complain.